# SSO button does not appear on Salesforce Cloudforce.com login page (with MS Azure AD as Single Sign On authenticator)

Tags: single-sign-on, button, azure-active-directory

Does anyone recognize this situation and know of a possible solution?

For my Salesforce login, I want to use Azure AD as a Single Sign On (SSO) provider.

**On Azure AD**

- I have created the app on Azure AD according to the steps found on the web. I crosschecked with a number of pages from different providers (SF, MS, fairsailcustomersforlife), did not find a hint that I might have configured the Azure AD side incorrectly.
- I created a Metadata XML file to create the SAML Single Sign-On Settings on Salesforce

**My Domain**

- On the Domain Suffix setting of the My Domain Details section Cloudforce (*.cloudforce.com) has been configured.
- I have added this SSO on the My Domain page under the heading Authentication Service on the Authentication Configuration of the My Domain Settings

**Cloudforce Login page**

I expect a button to appear on the (Cloudforce) login page of this environment, **but it does not**. Can you help me understand why this is not the case?

Much obliged!

Comment: https://login.salesforce.com is a site/ portal to use to login to salesforce. It is a default option for My Domain.

Comment: https://www.gocloudforce.com is from MS